# Single inputstream containing two files.  I want to split those files

Tags: java, inputstream

In java I'm having an `inputstream` (maybe `sequenceinputstream`) containing more than one file. I want to separate those files using java. Is there any solution available in java?

Comment: How would you know where one stream ends and the next begins?

Comment: What is the reason you can not open the files in separate streams?

Comment: yes. i'm unable to identify start and end of the stream. or else shal i use some constant value in between the streams to differentiate the files. is it correct method to implement?

Comment: you seem to be reinventing the wheel.  Maybe use an FTP library?  FTP is one of a few protocols that defines how to send files over a stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is: you can't / shouldn't.

The complicated answer: in case you are dealing with a `SequenceInputStream`, you can access the underlying streams using this reflection hack:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Enumeration<InputStream> split(final SequenceInputStream sis){
    try{
        Field streamsEnumField =
            SequenceInputStream.class.getDeclaredField("e");
        streamsEnumField.setAccessible(true);
        return (Enumeration<InputStream>) streamsEnumField.get(sis);
    } catch(final Exception e){
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

But I would be *very* careful about using something like this.

Comment: Also, at that point what are you gaining by using a SequenceInputStream?  You know the set of InputStreams (since you're constructing the SIS with them) and you want to treat them individually so what's the point?

Comment: @Mark the only use case I can think of is when the SequenceInputStream was created by code you can't control

Comment: what is reflection hack? how can i use this ?

Comment: @Sathish you can use it by pasting it into a java source file of your choice and calling the method. It's a reflection hack because it uses [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to access internal state that's supposed to be hidden from access. This is evil, but sometimes evil things need to be done.

Comment: using httpclientrequest servlet i'm sending the sequenceinputstream of some files. While in server side i'm receiving inputstream as servletinputstream. Please tel me the ways to convert servletinputstream to sequenceinputstream. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what kind of files you have, if there is any reserved squence which indicates the End and/or the beginning of the file like HTML or XML etc. then you can separate them, otherwise i don't see any way to do this.

Comment: What is the file end sequence for XML or HTML?

Comment: Guess it would be </html> or any xml-End_Tag, am i wrong? So by saving the information localy and parsing it this should be possible.

Comment: The end of the corresponding root element :-)

Comment: :  That may often be the case, but really the root-ending node just represents the end of a certain data structure.  There could at the very least be whitespace or comments after.

Comment: @Mark: AFAIK in a valid html/xml fiel there should be no data after the closing root element, anyway html and xml was just an Example of data which has Enddata sequence, its up to the OP to decide what kind of Data he is receiving and if the data really valid or no.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some way of determining where one file ends and the next begins- most files reserve the first few bytes as an "identity" tag. Bear in mind that Java's insistence on having a SIGNED byte class can mess with identifying these at runtime.

However, you can't really split streams. So, you'll have to stage your data through ordinary byte[] arrays. I'd read from the parent stream in chunks of 4K (for files) or 64K (for the network) since the underlying native calls usually use those sizes, store the chunks in lists, and then create a ByteArrayInputStream for each file at the end.